# Centering if single line, but no centering if multiple lines

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to horizontally center align some text if it fits in a single line, but do not do center align and do `white-space: normal` if it takes up multiple lines (preferrably, but not necessarily, without javascript)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an HTML+CSS solution.

The tricks are:

1. The `<span>` inside `<p>` has the `display: inline-box;` property so it will shrink to the size of its content.
2. The `<p>` has `text-align: center` so the **`<span>`** will be centred if the size of the `<span>` is less than the width of the `<p>`.
3. The `<span>` has `text-align: left` so the **text** will actually be left-aligned.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
    <head>
        <title>Center</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .big-box {
                text-align: center;
                width: 40em;
                border: 1px solid red;
            }
            .center-if-single-line {
                text-align: left;
                display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Small</h1>
            <p class="big-box">
                <span class="center-if-single-line">
                    All your line are belong to us!
                </span>
            </p>
            <h1>Big</h1>
            <p class="big-box">
                <span class="center-if-single-line">
                    All your line are belong to us!
                    All your line are belong to us!
                    All your line are belong to us!
                    All your line are belong to us!
                    All your line are belong to us!
                    All your line are belong to us!
                    All your line are belong to us!
                    All your line are belong to us!
                    All your line are belong to us!
                    All your line are belong to us!
                    All your line are belong to us!
                    All your line are belong to us!
                    All your line are belong to us!
                    All your line are belong to us!
                    All your line are belong to us!
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A Javascript solution - not necessarily the best - would be to enquire about the height of the div/p and make a determination from there. You need to know the height the DOM element takes if there is only one line. If the height exceeds this value, you do one thing; if not, you do the other. You'd set your CSS to default to the more common occurence, and only change it in the minority of cases.

For example:

```
var tag = document.getElementById("id_here");

if(tag.offsetHeight > 18){
   tag.style.textAlign = "left";
   tag.style.whiteSpace = "normal";}
```

You could also use jQuery. Note that offsetHeight includes padding.

But you don't really want a Javascript solution. I can't think how you'd do it in CSS, mind you, because it involves dynamic styling. I'd tenatatively suggest it ain't possible.